# Why doesn't .mkv files play properly with ubuntu-restricted-extra?

Tags: 10.04, multimedia, totem, gstreamer, mkv

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 with `ubuntu-resticted-extra` installed. When I play .mkv with the default player, `totem` it causes the player to stop suddenly without any warning after a random amount of time!

Anybody else is having this problem? **Is there any workaround other than installing vlc??**

What I want to know is, Is it a bug in gstreamer? or I'm the only one facing this issue!

Comment: Try VLC media player. It plays almost every video format flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Its a BUG....in the meantime...

Install VLC

VLC is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVD, Audio CD, VCD, and various streaming protocols.

[image]

Open Synaptic application

Click on System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager.
In Settings -> Repositories, make sure you have an universe repository activated.

Search for vlc and install it, as well as vlc-plugin-pulse. You may also want to install mozilla-plugin-vlc.

If you are interested in streaming or transcoding, you should additionnally install libavcodec-extra-52 from a multiverse repository.
Command line way

You need to check that a universe mirror is listed in your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `gstreamer-ffmpeg`. This should give you better playback with .mkv files. If it does not, then use another player (other than totem), such as VLC, or GNOME-Mplayer.

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extra contains ffmpeg http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-restricted-extras... So, it will not help!!!

Comment: @VineetMenon oh my mistake. I did an install for someone recently (but this was 11.10) and I had to install it manually. Try another player.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Gstreamer.

Else you can try Mplayer 
http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html

Answer (score -1):

The above error is happening because there is no libde265 plugin, run the following and it will work. I just did it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```