# Cannot seek mkv files in Totem Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: totem

When i try to seek an mkv file in totem, it automatically closes without any error dialog.
I have the three gstreamer plugins installed (good, bad and ugly)

**EDIT:** The following error message is displayed when i seek and video -

> gst_video_codec_frame_ref: assertion 'frame != NULL' failed ; Segmentation fault

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt-t, run `totem`, edit the question if there any error message in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing **ubuntu restricted extras** if you have not already

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Also check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79131/why-doesnt-mkv-files-play-properly-with-ubuntu-restricted-extra)